# função for para não repetir o laço

Tags: python

```py
deze = []
df["1_Dezena"][0:10]
for a in (df["1_Dezena"][0:10]):
    deze.append(int(a))
    print(deze)
```

Resultado:

```
[41]

[41, 9]

[41, 9, 36]

[41, 9, 36, 6]

[41, 9, 36, 6, 1]

[41, 9, 36, 6, 1, 19]

[41, 9, 36, 6, 1, 19, 56]

[41, 9, 36, 6, 1, 19, 56, 53]

[41, 9, 36, 6, 1, 19, 56, 53, 55]

[41, 9, 36, 6, 1, 19, 56, 53, 55, 25]
```

Porém gostaria que aparecesse: [41, 9, 36, 6, 1, 19, 56, 53, 55, 25].

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Olá.

Você está usando método print dentro do for e cada loop está mostrando o valor atual das dezenas, use quando o for termina.

Solução:

```py
deze = []
df = {"1_Dezena": [0,1,2,1,21,3,4,8,4,34]}
df["1_Dezena"][0:10]
for a in (df["1_Dezena"][0:10]):
    deze.append(int(a))
print(deze)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda… Consegui resolver

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda… Consegui resolver

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda… Consegui resolver com a sua correção.